# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"profile"})

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I inherited an old Rails app and I'm really struggling with this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError 
    (No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"profile"}):
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:59:in
    `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__105<snip>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40:in `index'
```

I ONLY get this error when I log in as admin, not as any other user.

Here is my routes.rb

```
Vvault::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders

  devise_for :users

  resources :videos

  resources :users

  root :to => "users#index"

  match 'users/:id/profile' => 'users#profile', :as => :user_profile
end
```

I think this is the relevant snippet from users_controller.rb:

```
def index
  if current_user.admin?
    # admin sees all users
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  else
    redirect_to "/users/" + current_user.id.to_s() and return
  end
end
```

I think this is the relevant snippet from application_html.erb:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to "My account", user_profile_path, :method => :get %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

If i comment out the third line of application_html.erb I can login as admin, but obviously the profile link does not render for any user.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to "My account", user_profile_path(current_user.id), :method => :get %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_profile_path` helper needs an `id` to be passed in, as the corresponding route has an `:id` parameter.

The error message is telling you that no route exists for that controller/action combination without any other parameters.

Or, you need to define a route *without* an `id` parameter where the controller automatically loads the current user's profile

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the id to `user_profile_path`. But since that route points to the user's account, there is no point in setting the id, because it should always be the current user (is that your intention?). If this is the case, then you can rewrite the route as:

```
match 'users/profile' => 'users#profile', :as => :user_profile
```

If not, then provide an id to the helper method for your route.